# Jupyter MathJax Physics package

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, mathjax, jupyter-lab

MathJax3 includes a [port of the physics package](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/physics.html), which I would like to use inside jupyter notebook / lab.

**What are the steps necessary to use this extension? 
 Can it be done without writing custom config files (important for collaboration)?**

I tried installing the [MathJax3 renderer](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers) for jupyter, but it seems that it does not recognize the `\require` command used to enable the extension. Another user already formulated an [issue on github](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers/issues/229) in September, but with no answers yet unfortunately.